# How to make Windows Search work with custom HTML META tags?

Tags: windows-search

Using Windows Search on Win2008.
I'm searching programmatically, using Microsoft.Search.Interop (CSearchQueryHelper, etc).
I have existing html files that include META tags in the header:

```
<meta name="fooo" content="baaa" />
```

I need to be able to search on these (query for "fooo:baaa") and also return the values in the result set.  (I was able to do this with the old Indexing Service.)

I tried adding a "fooo" property to the Property System (PSRegisterPropertySchema).  I can now use "fooo" in QuerySelectColumns without error, but the data never comes back.  Also CSearchQueryHelper does not seem to recognize "fooo:" as a property constraint.

Searching for unqualified "baaa" returns the document. (baaa does not appear anywhere beyond the meta tag.)